# How to get last datas from an output in R

Tags: r

Hope you are well.

As I am not familiar with R, I don't know how to get the last datas from a time series output.

Here is the script :

```
fit_arima<-auto.arima(DATA$CLI,d=1,D=1,stepwise = FALSE,approximation = FALSE, trace = TRUE)
fcst<-forecast(fit_arima,h=36)
print(summary(fcst))
```

Following that, I get these values as output :

```
371       99.87327 96.30132 103.4452 94.41044 105.3361
372       99.87327 96.24796 103.4986 94.32884 105.4177
373       99.87327 96.19538 103.5512 94.24842 105.4981
```

In fact, I would like to get col2&3 of the last line (373) in order to work with datas.
I tried to use `nail(fcst, n=1)` but it does not work...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Alex

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The output from `forecast` is a `list` (check the `str(fcst)`).  We could extract each of those components and get the `tail` and create a `data.frame`

```
data.frame(Mean = tail(fcst$mean, 1), lower = tail(fcst$lower, 1), 
     upper = tail(fcst$upper, 1), check.names = FALSE)
    Mean lower.80% lower.95% upper.80% upper.95%
1 216.798  115.8223  62.36906  317.7736  371.2269
```

There is also a `data.frame` method with `as.data.frame`

```
> grep("forecast", methods(as.data.frame), value = TRUE)
[1] "as.data.frame.forecast"  "as.data.frame.mforecast"
```

to convert the object directly to `data.frame` and then use the `tail`

```
 tail(as.data.frame(fcst), 1)
    Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
136        216.798 115.8223 317.7736 62.36906 371.2269
```

#### data

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
fcst <- forecast(fit,h=20)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I want to keep only the low & high 80, how can I do that ?

Comment: @AlexCauwel Once you convert to `data.frame`, it is easy to subset i.e. `tail(as.data.frame(fcst), 1)[, 2:3]`